# Open With from Chromebook file app doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive-api, google-chrome-os

I have a Google Drive app, which is registered as my default opener on Google Drive. This works perfectly fine when opening files using drive.google.com - When I open a file with my App, the app gets given permission to open the file and I can see that in the drive.google.com web interface.

However I recently tested this on a chromebook, and when I open a file using the Files app, I get sent to my app, however it gets a 'File Not Found' error. When I check the permissions for that file, my app hasn't been given access to it.

If I open the file using drive.google.com and then try opening using the files app again, it works since my app has been given access to the file when I opened it using drive.google.com

Seems there is a bug in the Files app on Chrome OS here, where it doesn't set the permissions to give the app opening the file permissions to access it, whereas the web interface does that correctly. Has anyone else run into this and/or should I report this as a bug to Google?

Using ChromeOS  5116.115.4  + Chrome 33.0.1750.152

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a bug, and it's fixed in the upcoming chrome 34: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332332